# How to make this "img" element behave as if in the normal flow?

Tags: html, css

So this is my markup, it's basically an image gallery.

```
<div class="img">
 <div class="cont"><a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></a></div>
 <div class="desc">This is the awesome logo</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
 <div class="cont"><a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></a></div>
 <div class="desc">This is the awesome logo</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
 <div class="cont"><a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></a></div>
 <div class="desc">This is the awesome logo</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
 <div class="cont"><a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></a></div>
 <div class="desc">This is the awesome logo</div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS

```
 div.img {position:relative;
          margin:5px;
          border:1px solid #000;
          padding:0;
          width:300px;
          height:300px;
          float:left; 
 }
 div.cont {
          position:absolute;
          left:50%;
          margin-left:-125px;
 }
 div.img img {
          margin-top:5px;
          border:1px solid white;
          padding:0;
          width:250px;
          height:250px;
 }
 div.desc {
          text-align:center;
          color:black;
 }
 div.img a:hover img {
          border:1px solid #666;
}
```

Basically my problem is I want the "img" element to behave as if it's in the normal flow, so that my "desc" div can acknowledge it as a block-level element and position itself below the image (which is a logo, by the way) exactly the way I want it, I know that absolute-positioned elements are taken away from the normal document flow, that's why my "desc" div is behind the image because it behaves as if the "img" element isn't there at all, which is not what I want.

I know this can be solved by changing the "cont" div to position-relative, but I want answers for position-absolute only because I feel like it's really important to tackle this specific problem and the specific situation, thanks.

Comment: I'm curious to know what this is supposed to look like because it's not clear from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrKnJ)

```
div.img {position:relative; margin:5px; border:1px solid #000; padding:0; width:300px;       height:300px; float:left; text-align:center; }
 /*div.cont {position:absolute; left:50%; margin-left:-125px;}*/
 div.img img {margin-top:5px; border:1px solid white; padding:0; width:250px; height:250px;}
 div.desc {text-align:center; color:black;}
 div.img a:hover img {border:1px solid #666;}
```

Comment: It works, I see you have added a "text-align:center" there, effectively rendering my "cont" div  irrelevant, but I thought that  property only works for texts?

Comment: `text-align:center` works on inline elements (including text) but images are also inline elements by default. You can do the same by setting the image to `display:block` and centering using `margin: auto` - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/iCHGm

Comment: Aren't text block level elements?

Answer (score 0):

How about positioning the `desc` div by giving it `bottom 0; position:absolute;`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/360/

CSS:

```
div.desc {
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px; //Can be any value depending on your design.
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cause layout problems on different screen resolutions? especially if set in pixels?

PS: And by the way, the "desc" div is perfectly aligned in the center, which doesn't happen in your version.

Comment: I guess not. Because the relative parent div.img has the dimension in pixels.